# TFS2015 access issue

Tags: tfs-2015

I am new on VS2015 Universal Platform projects and TFS2015.I create a tfs account and new uwp projects. Give permission to another account to build together. However, teammate can see the projects but not all of them. Solution(.sln) file MainPage and .cs files is not visible in his workspace folder. You guys any idea about this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Permission right usually given on team project level basic. However, in tfs there are also a team project collection level.

If you want to make everyone can see and operate each others project, you need to put your team group into Project Collection Administrators in Collection level

If you don't want everyone have admin right, you need to tell everyone to put the team group into **Contributors** group in the team project they created.

> Please note:
>
> For almost all permissions, **deny trumps allow**, so if a user belongs to
>   two groups, and one of them has a specific permission set to deny,
>   that user will not be able to perform tasks that require that
>   permission even if they belong to a group that has that permission set
>   to allow.

So for your solution, add your teammate in  contributors group of the team project. And make sure there are no deny permission of read in his account.